# Pdf-tools fails to print

Tags: pdf-tools, print

Using pdf-tools I attempt to print via `pdf-print-misc-document` though nothing gets printed?

In messages I see without any errors:
`Print job started: /usr/bin/lpr -P myprinter -o media=a4 -o InputSlot=Tray2 /home/temp.pdf`

Running the same command from the terminal prints immediately

```
$ /usr/bin/lpr -P myprinter -o media=a4 -o InputSlot=Tray2 /home/temp.pdf
```

.spacemacs

```
(custom-set-variables
'(pdf-misc-print-programm "/usr/bin/lpr") 
'(pdf-misc-print-programm-args (quote ("-P myprinter" "-o media=a4" "-o InputSlot=Tray2")))
)
```

Comment: This is probably not the source of the issue but I think that you're supposed to be using `pdf-misc-print-program` rather than `pdf-misc-print-programm`. The latter is an alias to the former,